# loopback with async library get in serial callback issue while sending one result callback to other

Tags: node.js, strongloop, loopback, async.js

I'm using the loopback for backend API, here for fetching the data from MySQL, here while performing the operation on it I am using the `async npm` library,

to perform block-level functional execution, while doing these facing setback with an autocallBack functional issue.

`Unhandled rejection TypeError: autoCallback is not a function`

here is my pseudo code.

```
ModalName.remoteMethod = function (data, cb) {
    async.auto({
      firstCallingFunction: function (autoCallback) {
        ModalName.find({
          id: 1
        }, yourResult => {
            if (err) {
                return cb({
                success: false,
                msg: 'Insufficient parameters',
                data: err,
                });
            } else {
                return autoCallback(null, yourResult);
            }
            });
        },
        secondCallingFunction: ['firstCallingFunction', function (autoCallback, result) {
            console.log('result=====>', result)
            ModalName.find({id: result['id']})
            .then(function(dbResult) {
            if (dbResult) {
                console.log('dbResult==========>', dbResult.toJSON());
                return autoCallback(null, dbResult);
            }
            });
        }],
    }, function (error, autoResult) {
      if (error) {
        return cb(null, error);
      } else {
        return cb(null, {
          success: true,
          msg: 'result fetched',
          data: autoResult.secondCallingFunction,
        });
      }
    });
  };
```

Get in ==> err in `autoResult`'s object function is undefined.

Any solution for that issue, please send.

Thanks.

Comment: You have to invert the parameters of `secondCallingFunction` like that : `function(result, autoCallback)`.

Comment: And also, your error management in `firstCallingFunction` is not correct. You should call `autoCallback(errorObject)` instead of `cb(errorObject)`. The original `cb` should only be invoked in the last callback of `async.auto` function.

Comment: hey, @dun32 thanks for the reply, you are all correct.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution, I just changed the function arguments and it works for me!

```
ModalName.remoteMethod = function (data, cb) {
    async.auto({
      firstCallingFunction: function (autoCallback) {
        ModalName.find({
          id: 1
        }, yourResult => {
            if (err) {
                return autoCallback({
                success: false,
                msg: 'Insufficient parameters',
                data: err,
                });
            } else {
                return autoCallback(null, yourResult);
            }
            });
        },
        secondCallingFunction: ['firstCallingFunction', function (result, autoCallback) {
            console.log('result=====>', result)
            ModalName.find({id: result['id']})
            .then(function(dbResult) {
            if (dbResult) {
                console.log('dbResult==========>', dbResult.toJSON());
                return autoCallback(null, dbResult);
            }
            });
        }],
    }, function (error, autoResult) {
      if (error) {
        return cb(null, error);
      } else {
        return cb(null, {
          success: true,
          msg: 'result fetched',
          data: autoResult.secondCallingFunction,
        });
      }
    });
  };
```